# Complex numbers FP1

Tags: complex-numbers

Let z = a + bi, where a and b are real numbers. If z/z* = c + di, where c and d are real, prove that c^2 + d^2 = 1.

I'm stuck and keep going round in circles. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know about the modulus of a complex number? And do you know that $|a/b| = |a| / |b|$?

Comment: Can you prove that $z$ and $z^*$ have the same magnitude? Then the ratio will have magnitude 1.

Comment: hold on ignore comment I was thinking something else xD

Comment: How do you get $c^2+d^2$ if $c+di=(a^2 + 2abi - b^2)/(a^2 + b^2)$?

Comment: Multiply by c-di

Comment: Which I did but I'm not sure where I've gone wrong

Comment: Could you try it please?

Comment: What's your $c=?$ and what's your $d=?$.

Comment: For some reason I can't get to a point where I have c = ? and d = ? I've only reached up to b^2 + c^2 = a^2 c + 2abci - b^2 c - adi + 2abd + b^2 di

Comment: Noooo, you had the equation before. it's up in the comments I made too. The question is can you separate the real part from the imaginary part of $$\frac {a^2+2ab(i)-b^2}{a^2+b^2}.$$

Comment: Oh I see.. so c = (a^2 - b^2)/(a^2 + b^2) & d = (2ab)/(a^2 + b^2)

Comment: Yep! and now I'm placing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{z}{z*}= \frac{a+bi}{a-bi}$ which is the same as $\frac{a+bi}{a-bi} \frac{a+bi}{a+bi} = \frac{(a+b i)^2 }{(a+bi)(a-bi)}= \frac{a^2+2ab i-b^2}{a^2+b^2} = \frac{a^2-b^2}{a^2+b^2}+i \frac{2ab}{a^2+b^2}$ which means that $c=\frac{a^2-b^2}{a^2+b^2}$ and $d=\frac{2ab}{a^2+b^2}$ so $c^2+d^2 = \frac{(a^2-b^2)^2+(2ab)^2}{(a^2+b^2)^2} = \frac{a^4-2a^2b^2+b^4+4a^2b^2}{(a^2+b^2)^2} = \frac{(a^2+b^2)^2}{(a^2+b^2)^2} = 1$

Answer (score 1):

Much shorter solution following the idea of John Hughes ($z\ne 0$ is required):
$$|z^*| = |z|\implies |z/z^*| = |z|/|z^*| = 1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let me show you a different way than Ahmad. Though his way works just as well. Let $z= a+bi$ where $a,b\in \mathbb R$. Then, 
$$\frac {z}{z^*}= \frac {a+bi}{a-bi}= \frac{a+bi}{a-bi}\cdot \frac{a+bi}{a+bi}= \frac{a^2-b^2}{a^2+b^2}+\frac{2ab}{a^2+b^2}i=c+di .$$
So for $c^2+d^2 = (c+di)(c-di)$ we have
$$\frac{(a^2-b^2)+2abi}{a^2+b^2}\cdot\frac{(a^2-b^2)-2abi}{a^2+b^2}= \frac{a+bi}{a-bi}\cdot \frac{(a-bi)^2}{(a+bi)(a-bi)}=1$$